# Prompt error message for python

Tags: python

```
def choosing_room():
    print "Welcome! You now must choose!"
    answer = raw_input("Type a or b and hit Enter")
    if answer == 'a' or 'A':
        print "You chose 'a'!"
    elif answer == 'b' or 'B':
        print "You chose 'b'!"
    else:
        print "That is incorrect, please try again"
        choosing_room()

choosing_room()
```

This is my code. It's very simple, but for some reason it keeps returning and error message of `reference error: 'prompt' is undefined`

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING?! And could you provide the full traceback?

Comment: 1. Your error message does not match the code. 2. The comparison `answer == 'a' or 'A'` must be `answer == 'a' or answer == 'A'`

Answer (score 0):

As @Bhargav Rao commented, your code **does not** match your error, when you run it you will get an output of `a` regardless of what you enter.

This is because `if answer == 'a' or 'A':` is the same as saying:

`if answer == 'a':`  OR  `if 'A':` <-- this is always true

To fix this you can use the condition `in`:

```
def choosing_room():
    print "Welcome! You now must choose!"
    answer = raw_input("Type a or b and hit Enter: ")
    if answer in ['a','A']:
        print "You chose 'a'!"
    elif answer in ['b','B']:
        print "You chose 'b'!"
    else:
        print "That is incorrect, please try again"
        choosing_room()

choosing_room()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not going to solve the problem you are having (although the code worked for me in an iPython shell), there is an issue with your if/else statements. The following statement:

```
    if answer == 'a' or 'A':
        print "You chose 'a'!"
```

will always print "You chose 'a'!" regardless of the letter you enter upon prompting.  In python, the `or` expression you are using asks the following question:  Is the answer given equal to 'a' OR is the boolean value of "A" `True`?  What you mean to ask is: Is the answer given equal to 'a' OR is the answer given equal to "A"?  This is most concisely represented through:

```
if answer.lower() == 'a':
    print "You chose 'a'!"
```

That should solve at least one problem that this code is having.